# Mount local SSD drive in container

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

With [GKE 117.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes#google_container_engine_1), local SSDs are supported with the `--local-ssd-count` option when creating clusters. Having tried this option I can see the additional SSD volume mounted in the nodes, but how can I access it from the containers?

I was looking for a corresponding value to the `Volumes.emptyDir.medium` attribute, or something similar, but I haven't found anything in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Overview of Local SSD support](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/local-ssd) you can access the local SSD using a `hostPath` volume.

Comment: As `hostPath` is a somewhat limiting option, is there anything fundamental that prohibits using it with `emptyDir`? I mean, could it be a future enhancement?

Comment: There is ongoing work to have better support for local storage. Mounting and formatting local SSDs and using a `hostPath` can be considered a temporary solution (that is available now) until we have implemented proper data gravity in Kubernetes.