# Can I use local SSDs on GKE for fast, temporary storage within a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We have an application deployed on GKE that would benefit from having fast temporary storage on disk.

The GKE [local SSD](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd) feature is almost perfect, however we have multiple pod replicas and would ideally like to support multiple pods on the same node. Mounting the local SSD using `hostPath` makes that difficult.

[This 2016 SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720828/mount-local-ssd-drive-in-container) mentions the idea of mounting `emptyDir`s on the local SSD which would be perfect, but I understand still isn't an option.

There is a [2017 mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/IVg6QasyxV0) with the same idea, but the answer was still not positive.

The [GCP docs for local SSDs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd) were recently updated to describe using them via the `PersistentVolume` abstraction, which sounds sort of promising. Could I use that to achieve what I'm after?

The examples seem to show mounting the full local SSD as a `PersistentVolume`, when my preference is to use an isolated part of it for each pod. We also don't need the data to be persistent - once the pod is deleted we'd be happy for the data to be deleted as well.

Comment: This community spec seems to expose a lot of the design thinking behind making local SSDs available via PersistentVolume (https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/storage/local-storage-pv.md). It sounds like maybe the "temporary storage space" use case wasn't the primary goal, so maybe what I'm looking for isn't possible yet

Comment: I've discovered an alpha feature added in kubernetes 1.11: [Downward API support in volume subPath](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48677). I haven't tested it yet, but the description sounds like it might be possible to mount the local SSD via hostPath, and then use the pod name as a subDir

Comment: While reading the different options you thought, it seems to me using the hostPath suits to your use case best. Are you facing any specific challenges/difficulties with this option while using Local SSD?

Comment: A hostpath volume means a single pod gets access to the whole local SSD. I'd like each pod to have an isolated chunk of the local SSD

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes 1.11 added an alpha feature called [Downward API support in volume subPath](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48677), which allows volumeMount subpaths to be set using the downward API.

I tested this by creating a GKE 1.11 alpha cluster:

```
gcloud container clusters create jh-test --enable-kubernetes-alpha
  --zone=asia-southeast1-a --cluster-version=1.11.3-gke.18
  --local-ssd-count=1 --machine-type=n1-standard-2 --num-nodes=2
  --image-type=cos --disk-type=pd-ssd --disk-size=20Gi
  --no-enable-basic-auth --no-issue-client-certificate
  --no-enable-autoupgrade --no-enable-autorepair
```

I then created a 2-replica deployment with the following config:

```
      env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
      volumeMounts:
        - name: scratch-space
          mountPath: /tmp/scratch
          subPath: $(POD_NAME)
  volumes:
    - name: scratch-space
      hostPath:
        path: "/mnt/disks/ssd0"
```

If I `kubectl exec`'d into each pod, I had a `/tmp/scratch` directory that was isolated and very performant.

If I SSHd into the host, then I could see a directory for each pod:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/disks/ssd0/
drwx--x--x 14 root root 4096 Dec  1 01:49 foo-6dc57cb589-nwbjw
drwx--x--x 14 root root 4096 Dec  1 01:50 foo-857656f4-dzzzl
```

I also tried applying the deployment to a non-alpha GKE 1.11 cluster, but the SSD content ended up looking like this:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/disks/ssd0/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  1 04:51 '$(POD_NAME)'
```

Unfortunately it's not realistic to run our workload on an alpha cluster, so this isn't a pragmatic solution for us yet. We'll have to wait for the feature to reach beta and become available on standard GKE clusters. It does seem to be [slowly progressing](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/64604), although the API [will probably change slightly](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/pull/2871).

For kubernetes 1.14, the syntax for `volumeMounts` has changed to use a new `subPathExpr` field. The feature remains alpha-only:

```
      env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
      volumeMounts:
        - name: scratch-space
          mountPath: /tmp/scratch
          subPathExpr: $(POD_NAME)
  volumes:
    - name: scratch-space
      hostPath:
        path: "/mnt/disks/ssd0"
```